# A philosophy professor or philosopher-professor?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, education

**Reading this [job description](https://www.jobs.cam.ac.uk/job/44197/) for the position of Assistant Professor in Philosophy at Cambridge, one of the key questions that comes to mind is:**

- ***does an academic certification/position in philosophy make you a philosopher or do you get an academic certification/position in philosophy because you are a philosopher?***

**A related question that comes to mind is:**

- ***would anyone here, more so, moderators qualify for this job, if not, does that discredit their competence to tackle philosophical matters?***

*Note: I am not affiliated to Cambridge University, this is merely a study sample.*

[image: Assistant Professor in Philosophy]

[image: Person specification]

Answer (score 2):

Whether you qualify as X depends on how X is defined.

In most discussions the definition of X is either "common knowledge" so to say it's part of the everyday vocabulary or if you really want to stress the meaning of a word you need to provide and agree upon a new and more rigorous definition.

Now in this case the Cambridge University has provided a definition of what it means in their books to be a "philosophy professor at Cambridge". Though that does not mean that this is the universal definition of a (professional) philosopher it's just the title of a job that they are willing to spend between $45,585 and $57,696 on. They could just as well have called it an "intergalactic space ninja" or more accurately a "fame and money maker (for the philosophic institute", because that is apparently what is "essential" to THAT job.

So as having a PhD in philosophy is a formal requirement for that job, a "love of wisdom" (which is what philosophy means in the literal sense) may not suffice (unless it took you to such an academic degree).

So that is similar to asking whether you need a drivers license to (be able to) drive or whether you need to show your ability to drive to receive a drivers license.

And no you don't need a license to be able to drive, in fact you need to be able to drive before you get your license. What that license signifies is that you have been tested to have a certain curriculum of knowledge and skills. So if you have obtained that license legally you can verify to someone else, without additional testing, that you are capable of XYZ. If you should then fail on doing that, this blame goes to the institution providing you the certificate.
On the other hand you could also be capable of all these things without ever taking a test, I mean lots of knowledge is freely available and whether you learn that under the title of a student or in your spare time doesn't make a practical difference. Sometimes it helps to have a mentor who sees where you struggle and can assist and supplement you, while in other cases struggling through something and finding an insight for oneself could also be a worthwhile experience.

Though the more independent you are in your study the more likely it is that you'll have found your own curriculum and developed your own lingo and ideas, which could be a good thing, but also can make a communication with professionals quite difficult because you might end up being an expert in one domain while also making mistakes that are covered in 101 classes. So the with regards to a description of a certain curriculum you'd likely fail such a definition and would likely be required to take the official route to that.

The other problem is that it's not just a skill that you acquire and have, you likely want to actually find answers and further the quest of knowledge and to that end you need to keep up with the status quo of the arguments, the data and be able to contribute your own ideas. And in some cases the discussions can take place in elite circles of high ranking journals where you have to pay to publish (because other's need to proof read it) and where the payment is reputation and fame, which in turn might give you job offers, external money and students to exploit. But which is an occupation that you likely can't afford if that isn't your full time job.

Not an example from philosophy, but take that guy:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan

He's listed as mathematician despite having next to no formal training in it, yet he contributed to it substantially and suffered from most of the problems mentioned before:

"he tried to interest the leading professional mathematicians in his work, but failed for the most part. What he had to show them was too novel, too unfamiliar, and additionally presented in unusual ways; they could not be bothered"

The problem is that for every Ramanujan there's also tons of people who suffer from a more Dunning-Krueger like problem, where the lack of knowledge prevents them from seeing how superficial their own knowledge actually is. Like there are tons of people who regularly want to proof Einstein and other famous physicists wrong while lacking even basic knowledge. To the point where professionals usually just dismiss that as nonsense because otherwise they wouldn't be able to do anything else with their day. Often times the most damning reaction to garbage in academia is not a rebuttal but just ignoring it.

Comment: *"So as having a PhD in philosophy is a formal requirement for that job, a "love of wisdom" (which is what philosophy means..) may not suffice."* Alas! tragedy of the moderns. Reminds me of Randall Collins' book, *"The Sociology of Philosophies."*, were he uses his *interaction ritual chain* model to explain how settings like universities incubate an "argumentative community" whose "rituals" (lecturing, etc.) are specialized for & meaningful only to academics, creating a "thought community" immune to creativity, hence leads to stratification & solidarity i.e., "coalition in the mind."

Answer (score 2):

The reason that most academic doctorates, regardless of discipline, are called "Doctorate of *Philosophy*" is because a professor is expected to be more than a teacher, and more than a practitioner. They are expected to have a wide grounding in their field, including technique and history, but also the larger questions that fall into the realm of the "philosophy" of that field (whatever it may be).

Similarly, the professor of philosophy is classically conceived not just as a teacher of philosophy, but also as a philosopher in their own right. While there do exist careerist philosophy professors, it's generally a field that people enter because of their interest in practicing philosophy, not just studying it. It's worth noting that, unlike with many other fields, there's no well-defined career-path for "philosopher" outside of academia. (Philosophers can and do excel in all fields, but generally not under that job-description.) With few exceptions, if you want philosopher to be your (paid) job, you must enter academia.

Anecdotally, philosophy classes, regardless of their putative focus, do tend to inevitably be classes in the particular philosophies of their professors. Philosophy, by definition, deals with unsolved and controversial questions with no widely-acclaimed objective answer, so the individual beliefs of the professor will inevitably impact the way they present the material, to a much greater extent than in more objective fields. (This is true even in survey classes, due to the necessity of curating the sources.)

Comment: *"the individual beliefs of the professor will inevitably impact the way they present the material"* so a new priesthood. *"individual beliefs"* is what you'd expect from a Jesuit, whose fanatical beliefs on discernment and obedience to doctrine/dogma guide their educational focus, but then again unsurprising, when you consider the history of universities. Your point that *"there do exist careerist philosophy professors"* leaves one wondering if only a *"career philosophy professor"* can successfully survive an environment pedagogically designed to sniff out intellectual vitality.

Comment: @al-Mu'tamid I'd say rather that the careerist philosophy professor is the one who has already allowed the academic environment to snuff out his/her intellectual vitality.

Comment: *"allowed the academic environment to snuff out his/her intellectual vitality."* a chillingly apt way of describing *"The Death of Reason"*, which leaves one wondering of motive. What motive would drive a human being to consciously allow the most essential vitality that distinguishes him/her from beasts of burden to be senselessly snuffed out? Money cannot be it, something far more sinister must be at play.